# ¿Qué significa el error mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi aplicación PHP me lanza el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version
>   mismatch. Headers:100023 Library:50544 in

El error apunta a la siguiente línea:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

A pesar del error, el código sigue funcionando.

Días atrás no mostraba ningún error. Estoy usando un web hosting gratuito.

¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Parece como si alguien hubiera actualizado algo, y las versiones ya no son compatibles

Comment: y que tendría que actualizar en mi codigo para solucionar?

Comment: Primero tendriamos que diagnosticar bien que fue lo que paso, mi fuerte no es php, deberiamos esperar a alguien mas conocedor, para saber que mover

Comment: dudo que sea el código el problema, suena a líos con librerías.

Comment: @JESUSESPINOSA, lo que menciona jasilva es verdad, algo se actualizo y no es compatible.

Comment: Peor entonces no depende de mi sino del hostin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sucede que PHP fue compilado con una versión diferente a la de la librería de MYSQL que estás usando.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Actualizar PHP para que coincida con la versión de MYSQL (es muy probable que el hosting gratuito no te lo permita).
2. Cambiar la versión del cliente de MYSQL que estás usando para que coincida con la versión que fue compilada para PHP.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Dados tus comentarios veo que tu hosting actualizó tu versión de `Cpanel` a `11.50.5.0` lo cual, según [esto](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/11.50+Change+Log), también actualizó la versión de `mysql` a `5.6.29` mientras que tu `libmysql` sigue siendo de la versión `5.1.73`. Por eso te sale el `warning`.

La solución sigue siendo cualquiera de los pasos que puse arriba.

Comment: cpsrvd 11.50.5.0
Versión del cliente de base de datos: libmysql - 5.1.73
extensión PHP: mysqli

Comment: @JESUSESPINOSA he actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: y como puedo cambiar la versión del cliente MYSQL

Comment: al parecer se soluciono solo, ya no aparece el mensaje

Comment: Me alegro de leer eso. Eso me hace pensar que tu hosting actualizó ambas cosas pero no al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto al mensaje de error se puede deducir que tienes alguna librería que usa versión `MySQL` diferente.

¿Que has actualizado?, revisa la versión de `MySQL` que usa `php` y las de tus librerías!

Te sugiero desde la línea de comandos obtener más información:

```
$ php -i
```

Comment: ¿linea de comandos? en php admin

Comment: Me refería a PHP http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: @JESUSESPINOSA definitivamente es eso, algo se actualizo y ahora no es compatible, encontré una pregunta similar en inglés http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759334/headers-and-client-library-minor-version-mismatch

Comment: gracias por responder, por lo que tengo entendido debo encontrar el archivo php.ini, pero no lo hallo vía FTP